# Replacing Substring in Line between Anchors

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed

I have a text file with a line that reads:

```
<div id="page_footer"><div><? print('Any phrase's characters can go here!'); ?></div></div>
```

I already asked in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289913/extracting-substring-from-string-with-multiple-special-characters-using-sed) about how to get the substring within the single quotes of the print statement above and got 2 good answers.  Now I'm wanting to know how either of them (or another answer) could be tailored to replace the substring within the single quotes of the print with another substring.  I'm leaning in the direction of using in-place sed like:

```
sed -i 's/[SUBSTRING_IDENTIFIER]/New page_footer is here' /home/foobar/testfile.txt
```

So `testfile.txt` would be edited to have this line changed to ...

```
<div id="page_footer"><div><? print('New page_footer is here'); ?></div></div>
```

I don't want to directly replace the found substring just in case it occurs elsewhere in the line; I want to use `print('` and `');` as anchors like in my other question and replace the substring in between them.  Suggestions?

Comment: Regular expressions are not the right tool for parsing HTML. You may be able to hack together something that will work for just your use case, but it will likely have difficulty handling perfectly valid format changes. Have you considered using a language that actually understands the DOM?  Python, PHP, Ruby,  even Perl or Lua. Or xml2json with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  But not sed.

Comment: If you got good answers to the other question, why are neither of them accepted?

Comment: @miken32 I was waiting to see answers here to see if one of their answers was tailored in some way to fit this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason this wouldn't work?

```
sed -i "s/print('.*');/print('New page_footer is here');/" testfile.txt
```

Comment: Just for good measure, I'm trying to expand the left anchor to include `><div><? print('` but it doesn't seem to like the great-than symbol even if I ecsape it with a backslash.  Do you know how I could get this working?  Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Angle bracket is not a special character in most places in a regular expression.